# Left align matrices in RMarkdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, markdown

I am trying to write some matrices and knit them to a PDF. My code (below) seems to work fine, but the default is to have it centered on the page. How do I left justify it?

```
$$\mathbf{A)} = \left[\begin{array}
{rrr}
4 & 7 \\
2 & 8 \\
1 & 9
\end{array}\right]$$
```

Answer (score 3):

just remove double dollar signs, keep one;

```
$\mathbf{A)} = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}4 & 7 \\2 & 8 \\1 & 9\end{array}\right]$
```

differences;

[image]